# Using {% include %} to reuse CSS in Django

Tags: html, css, django, tags, include

I'm having a weird problem in Django. Let me explain:

Some of CSS code was calling a background image stored in the static files with a `static` template tag like so

```
#listing:not(#foo) div > input + label {
        background: url('{% static 'img/listingSample.png' %}');
        width: 110px;
        height: 99px;
        margin-left: 6px;
        float: left;
        ....
```

so I had to move the CSS directly in the `listings.html` template file being called in the `views.py` or else the tag would not render.

This all worked fine, until I realized I have a totally different page that needs the same CSS. So what I did is I tried moving it out of `listings.html` and referring to it with an `{% includes %}` tag. However, now when I run the code, only some of the CSS works, but not all of it - mainly, this bit doesn't work:

```
#listing:not(#foo) div > input:checked + label {
        background: brown;
    }
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your assets are organized like this:

```
/static
    /css
        /main.css
    /img
        /listingSample.png
```

you can use absolute path in css:

```
#listing:not(#foo) div > input + label {
    background: url('../img/listingSample.png');
    width: 110px;
    height: 99px;
    ....
```